# UML Sequence Diagram in Dia?

Tags: uml, tool-uml, dia

What's a good workflow (usage procedure) for creating a UML Sequence diagram in Dia?

Answer (score 130, accepted):

From the UML Sheet of Special Objects (left toolbar, center palette, use drop-down to select "UML"), select the UML Object object, [image], and then place an object in your diagram.

Next, from the same UML Sheet, select the lifeline object, [image], and place it in your diagram.  Then connect the lifeline's uppermost line handle to the UML Object placed in the last step.

Use the UML Message object, [image], to connect one lifeline to another.

Right-click on the lifeline to adjust the lifetime of the object, or to add or remove connection points.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to add more than only one focus of control to a UML life line?
Unfortunately, it seems that there is only the possibility to add/remove connection points for a single life line, but not to add/split/remove focus-of-control-bars.

Comment: How about just using multiple lifeline objects stacked vertically?  I just tried, it seems to work okay.  In my topmost lifeline, I dragged the bottom dashed line up so much that it disappeared, and then for my bottom lifeline I connected its upper dashed line to the bottom of the focus-of-control bar on the lifeline above it.

Comment: @feuGene - thanks for the above.  Quick related question: is there a way to draw a self-referencing call in Dia?  I can't figure it out.  I posted a question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786539/how-to-draw-a-self-call-in-dia

Comment: @JDelage: answered your question.  The gist is: change the UML Message object's properties to have Message Type: Recursive.

Comment: you just made my day! i try to download bunch of alternatives just because i dident know how to extend life line :( thank you again!

Comment: Wow.  Just, whoa...  Ok, trying to switch to Dia (coming from Visual Studio) and the amount of manual work to create the sequence diagrams is just... I loved Dia up until this.  Gotta find an alternative now.

Comment: @aduncan911: Yes, there is a good amount of manual work here.  But it's pretty close to being a one-time thing, because once you get something you like you can just copy/paste it.

Comment: Did you find a way to properly draw conditional/loop blocks?